# Newly created multipolygon layer fails to save due to large file size

Tags: qgis, export, spatial-join, geopackage, file-size

I used the function "Join attributes by location" to join a number of polygon circles (a multipoylgon layer) with the values of the points (multipoint layer) that are "contained" within them. Using the function to calculate the new layer was completed within under 2min although the final table includes over 6Mio individual entries because many circles are overlapping (see picture below).
[image]
When trying to display the layer, QGIS is constantly loading and sometimes stops responding all together. So working with a temporary layer is not an option. However, when I try to save the temporary layer I keep getting error messages such as the one below, which appeared after a 45min. loading period when I tried to save the layer as a geopackage file:

```
Export to vector file failed.
Error: Feature write errors:
Feature creation error (OGR error: failed to execute insert : database or disk is full)
Feature creation error (OGR error: failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO "JoinedLayer" ( "geom", "old_fid", "NUMPOINTS", "VALUE", "PointID") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) - no such table: JoinedLayer)...
...Feature creation error (OGR error: failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO "JoinedLayer" ( "geom", "old_fid", "NUMPOINTS", "VALUE", "PointID") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) - no such table: JoinedLayer)Stopping after 1001 error(s)
Cannot find layer JoinedLayer.
```

I specifically tried saving it as a geopackage because saving to shapefile was not possible due to a file size that exceeds 4GB. Now I am confused why saving it as a geopackage doesn't seem to work either. My laptop has over 100GB of free storage, so a "full disk" shouldn't be the problem.
Do you know why saving as a geopackage might not work for me? (I have never used geopackage before, so I might be doing something wrong)
Or is there an alternative that might allow me to compress my file and display and work with it in QGIS?

Comment: Maybe try running the whole process for testing purpose for just a small sample of your data to see if you're able in principle to save Geopackages.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with a small file and it works without a problem!

Comment: It is probably you have FAT32 formatted disk in your laptop. FAT32 doesn't allow files bigger than 4 GB and you get "full disk" error. Use a NTFS disk to export.

Comment: That is indeed a hint that the problem could be related to limited disk space or something comparable...(?) Did you search for the error message (by theway: that's why you should **always** post error messages as text, not as image).

Comment: I am actually using a NTFS disk. And @Babel thanks for the correction, I'll do that next time. I couldn't find anything online when searching for the error though.

Comment: Is it possible that QGIS simply cannot handle layers with over 6 millions features? Or is there a way to compress (almost) any file, to be able to display and work with it in QGIS?

Comment: Try splitting up the whole process in several smaller regions